# Returning an array of objects in a php function

Tags: php, arrays

I have multiple rows getting returned from a database query.

I am able to get just a row at a time, but I want to put the rows in an array of objects like this:

```
$trailheads[] = new StdClass;
Loop
{
   $trailheads[] = $trailhead; // Put each object into the array of objects 
}
```

But when I try to loop through each array, I am having trouble extracting the values of each row.  What is the right way to loop through the returned object and get the values?

The code that does not work is pretty basic:

```
$returned_obj->o->trailhead_name
```

But I am actually hoping be able to loop through each array element.

Comment: Could you post the code that does not work?

Comment: Post here normal code sigment, and colored it

Comment: @stefgosselin Just edited my question with a small example

Comment: Please provide more code. You can't add elements to an object, just properties.

Comment: The issue is not in the loop, there is no loop in your code example. From what I see your issue is _before_ the loop! ;)

Comment: $trailheads[] = new StdClass; does not create an array of stdClasses, it creates an array, with the first element[], being a new StdClass() obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try casting to array in your for loop, this is untested and may not work as is but should get you on the right track:

```
foreach ($trailheads as (array) $key){

    // $key is now an array, recast to obj if you want  
    $objkey  = (object) $key;

}
```

Comment: Actually, for some reason, this gave an error: foreach ($trailhead_list->o as (array) $key)

Comment: Your outer variable was an array in your example, if $trailhead_list is your outer variable you need to use it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming your using mysql since you did not say...

you can use thsi function **[mysql_fetch_object()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)**

```
<?php
$trailheads = array()

$result = mysql_query("select * from mytable");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result, 'trailhead')) {
    $trailheads[] = $row;
}
```